# <Tab> keypress into buffer from function

Tags: vim, snipmate

I'm working on creating a function that will:

- Inspect the current file I'm working on
- Create a new buffer in my test directory based on my file name
- Edit that file and start my snipmate "test" template

So far I have everything working except triggering snipmate. What I'd like to do is insert a `<Tab>` character like I was in insert mode to trigger snipmate to kick off

```
" Only works for modules and models right now
function! MakeTest()
  " sub out any prefix
  let base_test_path = substitute(expand('%:r'), '\(lib/\|app/models/\)', '', 'g')
  execute 'edit ' . 'test/unit/' . base_test_path . '_test.rb'
  norm i test<Tab>
endfunction
```

Instead it is literally mapping to `test<Tab>` into my template. My guess is that I don't want to use `norm` for this, but I'm not too keen on what I should use instead.

Any thoughts?

Is there a way to enter insert mode from a function?

Comment: Try `exec "norm i test\t"`.

Comment: nice that worked! thanks! I didn't realize vim treats single quotes as literals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything after `:normal` is treated literally; to insert special characters, you need to use *double quotes* and `:execute` to evaluate them:

```
execute "norm i test\<Tab>"
```

For the tab key, you could have alternatively written `"\t"`; the `:help key-notation` is the more common and general one, though.